# iCloud Drive Preview folder shows persistent iCloud icon

Tags: icloud, preview

The Preview folder in iCloud Drive shows a persistent dashed-line iCloud icon. It has been showing the icon for hours even though all the files have most definitely been downloaded. The folder isn't particularly big either: only 40MB.

A reboot doesn't solve it. Any ideas on how to make it go away?

Comment: Do you have "Optimise Mac Storage" disabled in "System Preferences -> Apple ID -> iCloud". If yes try to enable it and disable it again.

Comment: @KevinGrabher No, I haven't.

Comment: If you have it enabled and have enough storage on your Mac you could try to disable it, that would force-download all the files from iCloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by disabling iCloud for Preview, removing the folder, enabling iCloud for Preview again and re-adding the files.

What exactly caused the problem I have no idea, but it's one of those things that really shouldn't happen in the first place.